# Invalid iOS Provisioning Profile (Distribution)

Tags: ios, apple, appstore, distribution

Подскажите, пожалуйста, iOS Provisioning Profile (Distribution) необходим только на момент публикации приложения в AppStore?
То есть, если в течение длительного времени (больше года) я не обновляю приложение и его Provisioning Profile переходит в статус Invalid, то я могу не пересоздавать его и никаких манипуляций с приложением не производить — приложение всё равно будет в AppStore и  всё будет ок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из [ссылки](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1878/_index.html) на документацию Apple:

> A provisioning profile attaining Invalid status due to App ID changes does not affect any currently deployed apps that were signed with that profile. It's just an indication that the profile must be regenerated/updated to reflect changes in services and entitlements made to its associated App ID before it can again be used for code signing.

Ни к каким это последствиям не приведет, приложения останутся в сторе, и все с ними будет в порядке.